# Using webhost to streamline .JSON files before passing

Tags: android, json

I'm working on an Android application that reads a dynamic .JSON file and displays the data in a ListView. The .JSON file is very large however, and as a result I end up with a 100MB JSONObject on my phone during tests and it takes up to 5 minutes for old devices to load.

The .JSON file used comes from a third party and I'm only using a small part (<0.1%) of it in my app. I'm very new to this kind of thing but I was wondering if it was possible for me to read the .JSON file from the third party on a webserver and isolate the data I need for my app into a new, smaller .JSON file that I host on the server for my app to request. The server would need a script to retrieve the newest version of the third party's .JSON file every few minutes and run the isolation script.

Is this possible? Is there a better solution? How would I go about this?

Comment: can you able to save the JSON to your server and save the wanted data , then write one service to get this in your app

Comment: Yes my question is if that's a good solution or if there are better ways to do this? My main concern lies with the bandwidth my solution would require.

Comment: i think that is the best way and i dot know any other best  way because you are  giving importance to bandwidth

Comment: Could you recommend me a good cheap/free host for these sort of things? And how would I write a script that refreshes the JSON every few minutes? What language should I use?

Comment: look around your place for hosting support, i will prefer php for this and if you are interested you can use C# also.You will get some good examples/service classes for download data ad you wish

Comment: I've been looking at hosts, but they don't allow purely hosting files - I need a website or I get shut down.